# Web Service on Windows Azure?

Tags: wcf, web-services, azure

I am new to Windows Azure and I have a question.

I have:

1. Web site which deployed to Windows Azure - The web site manage a table (add, edit, delete). I used this guide: [Deploying an ASP.NET Web Application to a Windows Azure Web Site and SQL Database](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/)
2. Andorid application & iOS Application (Native Code).

Now, I want the mobile applications to get data (in JSON format) from the web site (and from the DB).
**What is the best practice to do that?**

I tried to create a Azure (WCF) Service (the project refrenced to the web site project) but I didn't succeded. If this is the way - Is anyone knows a good tutorial to do that?
Is there another option? Maybe from the web site itself?

Thank you very much,
Yuval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to integrate with non-Microsoft technologies I suggest you take a look at the [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) which allows you to build REST services using [content negotiation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/04/22/asp-net-web-api-content-negotiation-and-accept-charset.aspx). Content negotiation allows your consumer to specify the format it requires (json, xml, ...).

To host the ASP.NET Web API in a Windows Azure Web Site you should take a look at Carlos' blog, he describes in detail what you need to do to make this work: [Creating ASP.NET Web APIs on Azure Web Sites](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/07/12/creating-asp-net-web-apis-on-azure-web-sites.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you given ASP.NET Web API a look-see?

http://www.asp.net/web-api